# Update proxy settings on a loaded kameleo virtual browser profile

Tags: web-scraping, browser-automation, kameleo

I was wondering if and how can I change the proxy using the update function,
I know of the function but I don't know the Property/format to change the proxy Ip:port of a loaded profile

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet to showcase how you can update the proxy settings on a reloaded virtual browser profile in Kameleo

```
profile = client.load_profile(body=LoadProfileRequest(path=path))
profile.proxy = ProxyConnectionTypeServerMultiLevelChoice(value='http', extra=Server(host='host', port=1111, id='user', secret='password'))
profile = client.update_profile(profile.id, body=profile)
```

Please note that you will need to import `Server` and `ProxyConnectionTypeServerMultiLevelChoice`

```
from kameleo.local_api_client.models.proxy_connection_type_server_multi_level_choice_py3 import ProxyConnectionTypeServerMultiLevelChoice
from kameleo.local_api_client.models.server_py3 import Server
```